# Conflict issue when multi developers work on same task

Tags: wordpress, themes, conflict

I am a Premium WordPress Theme Developer. During the development process Multiple developer working on same theme simultaneously and it create conflict issue as to make changes one developer enter there codes and update files.Mostly same files are open on other developers pc and when later own they save files the changes of developer 1 become lost and create lots of problems. Is there a better solution to tackle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: you can use version control to manage code. SVN or github

Answer (score 1):

Most web-developers have probably worked with some sort of revision control system, but designers may find it a foreign concept. The most obvious benefit of using revision control is the ability to have an unlimited number of people working on the same code base, without having to constantly send files back and forth.

**Git** is the new fast-rising star of version control systems.Git offers a much different type of version control in that it’s a distributed version control system.

**Subversion** is probably the version control system with the widest adoption. Most open-source projects use Subversion as a repository because other larger projects, such as SourceForge, Apache, Python, Ruby and many others, use it as well. Google Code uses Subversion exclusively to distribute code.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control/